# How do I override methods that have associated type parameters in subclasses?

Tags: swift, associated-types

What I tried to do:

```
protocol HasElement {
    associatedtype ItemType
    func getElement() -> ItemType
    func setElement(element: ItemType)
}

class Element {}
class BarElement: Element {}

class Foo: NSObject, HasElement {
    typealias ItemType = Element
    func getElement() -> Element { ... }
    func setElement(element: Element) { ... }
}

class Bar: Foo {
    typealias ItemType = BarElement
    override func getElement() -> BarElement { ... } // This works.
    override func setElement(element: BarElement) { ... } // This fails.
}
```

The error is:

> Method does not override any method from its superclass

If I try to use ItemType instead:

```
override func setElement(element: ItemType) { ... }  // Still fails.
```

The error is:

> 'ItemType' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried setting it as Element as well? Should be less "ambiguous"

Comment: Then I'd have to cast it to use it in the subclasses.  The whole point of this exercise is to not have to cast the darn thing all the time.

Comment: But yes, that does work.

Comment: Ah I see, that is an interesting problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do what you want:

```
protocol HasElement {
  associatedtype ItemType
  func getElement() -> ItemType
  func setElement(element: ItemType)
}

class Element {}
class BarElement: Element {}

class Foo: HasElement {
  // no need for typealias, the associated type is inferred
  func getElement() -> Element { return Element() }
  func setElement(element: Element) { }
}

class Bar: Foo {
  // no need for typealias, the associated type is inferred
  override func getElement() -> BarElement { return BarElement() }

  // hide the parent class method
  @available(*, unavailable, message: "Use setElement(element: BarElement)")
  override func setElement(element: Element) { }

  // comply with protocol in this class
  func setElement(element: BarElement) { }
}

// can't do this now:
let myElement = Element()
let myBar = Bar()
myBar.setElement(element: myElement) // Error: 'setElement(element: BarElement)' is unavailable: Use setElement(element: BarElement)
```

Comment: Interesting solution, although note that by overloading instead of overriding you lose dynamic dispatch, which may or may not be desirable. If you define `myBar` as `let myBar : Foo = Bar()`, then I would expect the `setElement(element:)` method from `Foo` to be called, rather than `Bar`'s method. Although what's interesting is that when doing that, neither method seems to get called – until you remove the unavailable attribute.

Comment: I agree that it may not be the best solution. I think that inheritance might not be the way to go, instead a protocol-based approach might give better results.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here isn't associated types, it's that method inputs are [*contravariant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)). Therefore you cannot override a method that expects a given superclass instance input with a method that expects a subclass instance input.

In fact, you can simply boil your code down to:

```
class Element {}
class BarElement : Element {}

class Foo {
    func setElement(element: Element) { }
}

class Bar : Foo {
    // error: Method does not override any method from its superclass
    override func setElement(element: BarElement) { }
}
```

You simply cannot override an `(Element) -> Void` method with a `(BarElement) -> Void` method. The reasons for this should be fairly obvious if you consider what would happen if you created a `Bar` instance and upcast it to `Foo`. You're now able to pass an `Element` instance to a method that expects a `BarElement` instance, which is illegal.

The reason it works for your `getElement` method is that method outputs are *covariant*. Therefore overriding a `() -> Element` method with a `() -> BarElement` method is perfectly legal, as even if you upcast a `Bar` instance to `Foo`, the `BarElement` instance returned from `getElement` can be freely upcast to `Element`.

As for solutions, it rather depends on your exact use case. It may well be that what you're trying to do doesn't require inheritance at all, and instead you can just conform `Foo` and `Bar` to `HasElement` separately.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
override func getElement() -> BarElement { ... }
```

using `override` keyword is when function signature does not change (`BarElement` is still `Element`). You copy and paste function from super class with same function name, same parameter name and same return value type.

But

```
override func setElement(element: BarElement) { ... }
```

fails because when you change parameter type (with same parameter name). 
This case is overloading not overriding.